# Fringing fields for capacitor with dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

I have read the report [Fringing Field Effect in Electrostatic Actuator](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.454.9033&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Vitaly Leus and David Elata. In this report, they present analytic methods to calculate the capacity of a mems device incorporating the fringing fields. The expressions are calculated for such a setup:

[image]

Now, I am wondering what would change, if a partial dielectric layer was introduced?

[image]

Comment: Not sure about the changes in the fringing field, but the capacitance should increase, if that's what you care about.

Comment: @V.F. Yes, exactly, but I need to know quantitively by how much ?